# Google charts wont let me use variables in row creation

Tags: javascript, php

I doing a school project where we need to create charts with data. I use google charts to create te charst. My codes works with static ints and it will make the charts:

```
 data.addRows([
                ['Debate', 1],
                ['Twitter', 1],
                ['Memes', 1]
            ]);
```

But when I try to do it with my variables it doesnt work:

```
data.addRows([
                ['Debate', debateCount],
                ['Twitter', twitterCount],
                ['Memes', memesCount]
            ]);
```

The variables have values so thats not the problem. I need to use vars in the rows because the vars has the values of my api which are correct btw. If somebody sees the problem pls help.

```
           ***vvvvv Code function vvvvv***
```

```
function drawChart(debateCount, twitterCount, memesCount) {

            debateCount = $('#set1').text();
            twitterCount = $('#set2').text();
            memesCount = $('#set3').text();

            console.log(debateCount);
            console.log(twitterCount);
            console.log(memesCount);

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', '');
            data.addColumn('number', '');

            data.addRows([
                ['Debate', 1],
                ['Twitter', 1],
                ['Memes', 1]
            ]);

            var options = {
                'title': 'Total entries of one day',
                'width': 400,
                'height': 300
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_pie'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            var chart1 = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_bar'));
            chart1.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Comment: "it doesn't work".....please be more explicit.   e.g., does it generate/display an error,  fail to render anything at all, or fail to render just part of the chart, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vars where strings like this:
debateCount = $('#set1').text();

You need to use parseInt to make it a int 0_0. Use it like this:
debateCount = parseInt($('#set1').text());